# проблема маршрута flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

мне надо решить задачу, если пользователь вручную введет в адресс браузере .то он попадет на нужную станицу.. но проблема в том что .когда ты ввел адресс, при нажатии еннтер присходит перезагрузка проекта . и получется что пользователь всегда будет возращаться на страницу в данном примере home .  у меня подожрения что flutter не преднозначен для сложных веб станиц к примеру если мой проект подразумевает партнерские ссылки или в данный момент мне нужно реализовать /home/agent  /home/clien то мне придется писать деревянным способом . просто в routes писать два этих маршрута.. но это еще не проблема проблема станет тогда когда мне надо будет получить /home/clien/id_client

```js
 String homePart = "home";
String url = window.location.href; // Получает текущий URL

Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
if (uri.hasFragment) {
  String fragment = uri.fragment; // Получает фрагмент URL (часть после '#')
  List<String> parts = fragment.split('/'); // Разделяет фрагмент на части

  if (parts.length > 1) {
    homePart = parts[1]; // Если есть хотя бы два сегмента, обновите 'home'
  }
}

String _link = "home";
print("new link $homePart");
switch (homePart) {
  case "home":
    _link = "home";
    break;
  case "first":
    _link = "first";
    break;
  default:
    _link = "home";
}

print(_link);
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/$_link"); // Замените на маршрут к вашей публичной домашней странице
});
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). начните с заголовка.